# How do I turn a JLabel into a button?

Tags: java, swing

So I have tried to turn my `JLabel` with an Image to a clickable button. But I ran into some problems.

Here's what I used:

```
Icon image = new ImageIcon("Image Path");
JLabel button = new JLabel(image);
button.setBounds(250, 100, 128, 64); //used a 500x200 window
frame.add(button);

button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.print("Hello");
      }
    });
```

So when I run the code I can click anywhere and I always get the `Hello` message.
But I only want the message to be printed out only when I click the image and not anywhere else.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

**Edit:
Heres what I really mean:

[image]

As you can see, there should be a blue box saying `Hello`.
and when I click it, I do get the message `Hello` but when I click outside the blue box(the white spots) I still get the message. Is there a way that I can disable that? So that when I only click the blue spot I get the message?**

Comment: Curious...Why not just use a JButton?

Comment: *But I only want the message to be printed out only when I click the image and not anywhere else.* - I have no idea what that means. If you are suggesting the label size is greater than the icon size, then your problem is the layout manager you are using. I see no reason for attempting to use a JLabel instead of a JButton.

Comment: *"I have tried to turn my JLabel with an Image to a clickable button."* It's easier to turn a button into something that *looks* like a label. [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556), for example, is made up of 5 labels (which don't act like buttons) and 4 buttons (which look like labels). Can you tell the difference between them? @camickr *"the label size is greater than the icon size"* A quick way to check. Add a visible border to the component. I generally use a red `LineBorder`.

Comment: General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, ..

Comment: .. they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: It's most likely because your JLabel is the same size as your JFrame. Use a Layout Manager to place your JLabel. For the heck of it try: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());`.

Comment: @Nightmarish Life, inspect the MouseEvent variable e, if it is fired by your component which is the JLabel button.

Answer (score 1):

You could just define a `Rectangle`, in whichs range a click on the `JLabel` should print your text. You can get the coordinates of your click relative to the `JLabel` with `getX` and `getY`. To check if the click is inside the rectangle you can use the method `contains`.
See [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) and [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html). A working example:

```
package labelbutton;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelButton {

    private static final Rectangle CLICK_FIELD = new Rectangle(140, 140, 200, 200);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.add(createLabelButton());
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static JLabel createLabelButton() throws MalformedURLException {
        Icon image = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://images.assetsdelivery.com/compings_v2/4zevar/4zevar1509/4zevar150900035.jpg"));
        JLabel button = new JLabel(image);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 3));

        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(CLICK_FIELD.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }
        });

        return button;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the `JLabel` into a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` and then add the panel to the frame. This way, the `JPanel` is going to occupy the extra space, while the `JLabel` is going to always be centered in it.

Here's a working example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            final JLabel button = new JLabel("Hello");

            button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    System.out.println("Hello label/button!");
                }
            });

            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN.darker()));

            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            panel.add(button);

            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label button");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How did I not think of that? Again. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. :)